# Reduce the size of Picker control on view iPhone

Tags: size, picker, reduce

I am working on Picker control and facing a problem of customising the size (**REDUCING THE SIZE OF UIPICKER** ) on the view.I tried it but it showed either the data in picker is overlapped or their is a  dark grey background on both ends of picker .Response needed badly

Thanks